# MySQL inserting text before and after value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have made an SQL query that picks out web statistics from a database.
This information is being picked out on a weekly basis, outputted as a HTML table and then sent by email.

One of the rows contains the IP addresses of the visitors.
I would like to make the IP address a link leadning to "http://whois.domaintools.com/ip.goes.here".

In HTML:

```
<a href="http://whois.domaintools.com/ip.goes.here">ip.goes.here</a>
```

Is there some way to put the A HREF code around each IP with an SQL query, or must I run some sort of script to convert each IP to a link?

I do not want to write anything to the database, only read from it.

Comment: Why not do that in the code that produces the HTML?

Comment: It was produced by the MySQL command line tool by using the -H switch. But now my question is answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `concat` function.

```
select concat(
  "<a href=\"http://whois.domaintools.com/", my_ip_column, 
  "\">", my_ip_column, "</a>"
) as my_ip_link from my_table;
```